# How to change route URL in Laravel 9 resource controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-9

I wondered if there is a way to change the default URLs of Laravel's resource controller. For example, for basic CRUD operation, for creating, we have a `/create` route made by default by Laravel. Can it be changed to `/ask` or `/new` or something like that?

Comment: surely you can, its just a naming convention which you call across your application like on routes or anywhere else.

Comment: yes, you can extend and bind to the `ResourceRegistrar` and change anything you want about how the resource routes are defined

Comment: I am fairy new to laravel and just learning it. It would be very helpful if you could provide me with some code..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can "localize" the resource URIs that are created without much work (Added to the `boot` method of a Service Provider):

```
Route::resourceVerbs([
    'create' => 'new',
]);
```

This would have all calls to `Route::resource(...)` create the URI with 'new' instead of 'create' for the `create` action.

If you need to get more complicated than something like that you could extend `Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar` to override it in any way you would like. You could call an instance of your version or bind it to the container for `Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar` which would use it for all `resource` calls.

[Laravel 9.x - Docs - Controllers - Resource Controllers - Localizing Resource URIs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#restful-localizing-resource-uris)